# How to remove null from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, null

I want to delete null elements in my array

```
 [ [ null, [ [Array], [Array] ] ] ]
```

The desired structure is 
`[ [[Array],[Array]], [[Array],[Array]],  [[Array],[Array]] ]`

if any of the objects are undefined/null such as :

```
[ [[Array],[]],  [[Array],[Array]],  [[Array],[Array]] ]
```

I wish to remove the full element `[[Array],[]]`

The 'yes' and 'no' are correctly identifying which elements have the undefined. So I know this code is functioning properly. I tried assigning the empty array as null and then filtering by adding to new array if != null but it did not work.

```
var filter = Total[0][i];

filter.forEach(e => {
    if ((e[0] !== undefined)&&(e[1] !== undefined)) {
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
        Total[0][i] = null;
    }
});

var totalArray = [];

const resultFilter = Total.filter(arr => arr != null);

var Filtereddata = resultFilter.filter(function(element) {
    return element !== null;
}
```

I am unsure how to remove the element or filter into a new array without null. 
The null Array is causing problems client side with extra `,` it would be better to remove the index/element altogether.

Comment: An empty array is not undefined or null

Comment: Please update the question with code creating example input, and with examples of the output you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just recursively filter out `null`s:

```
 const noNull = array => array
    .map(el => Array.isArray(el) ? noNull(el) : el)
    .filter(it => it !== null);
```

If you also want to remove empty arrays, you can replace `[]` with `null`:

```
 const noEmpty = array => array.length ? array : null;
```

Then change the recursive call from `noNull(el)` to `noEmpty(noNull(el))`

Comment: Fabulous, thank you very much!  this worked for me! :)

Comment: @annaM glad to help :)